# How to set an image file as your emblem in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

The topic says it all. I have seen many people with custom images as their emblem and I suppose they uploaded it from their computers but I cannot find how. I know you can draw it from available shapes but I am interested in uploading a jpeg, png file.

Comment: Not possible you'll just have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't upload a jpeg as an emblem. But there are lots of talented people that have created a vast array of different emblems for use.

Here a couple links you may find useful:

http://www.bf4blog.com/import-custom-battlefield-4-emblems/

http://www.reddit.com/r/bf4emblems

Answer (score -3):

I found a very helpful video showing how to do exactly what you want to do, upload your own or any image from your pictures on the hard drive of your computer.
Here is the instructions video... it is called 
"How to use any image inside the Battlefield 4 emblem editor!"
and it is located at this link;
Oh well, it won't let me give you a link here.
Just goto the Youtube search page and enter the title to his video, I forget his channel name but you don't need it, Just do a search for "How to use any image inside the Battlefield 4 emblem editor" in the searchbox on the YouTube page and it should take you to his video. I found it helpful. 
Just follow his steps, some are quite sophisticated as you need to use the HTML editor, but it is easy when you follow his steps shown in the very short video showing the very quick and easy solution to how to use any Image file as your emblem. 
Good luck,
Perry in FL

Comment: Just pointing people with the equivalent of, "Go search Youtube" isn't very helpful at all.  At the very least, include a link to which video you looked at, and summarize the information from the video.